# Please can someone point me towards drivers for HP printers, in particular for the HP2730e?

Tags: drivers, printing, hp

Using Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. I was born in 1940 and struggle with some aspects of Ubuntu. My new printer is intended to network using WiFi and Bluetooth (I think). I have the app and managed to recognise the printer, briefly, but no longer. I think I can set it up again but without the driver I can't expect it to print a file. HP do not list it in their library. Hoping someone has the patience to help.

Comment: Your first job is to connect the printer via Wifi to the network.  The WPS button  and printer front panel may be used for this. Then give the output of the command `driverless`.

Comment: Many thanks. Printer has its own Wi-Fi which works. Will follow yr advice for adding the printer to home network.